# What will be output of following code in different scoping and calling convention?

Tags: scope, pass-by-reference, lexical-scope, dynamic-scope, call-by-value

`int a = 2;`
`void f(int b){`
`b = b*a;`
`a = a-b;`
`}`

`void main(){`
`int a = 10;`
`f(a);`
`print a;`
`}`

a) Call-By-Value and Lexical Scoping
b) Call-By-Value and Dynamic Scoping
c) Call-By-Reference and Lexical Scoping
d) Call-By-Reference and Dynamic Scoping

My answer :
a) 10
b) 10
c) 20
d) 100

Please suggest me if i am doing something wrong ?

Comment: In second part, does the value of a will be affected to because of dynamic scoping. Value of a in function at the end will be -90. Does, it can affect the value of original a in main function scope ?

Comment: Slight correction.  answers will be 10, -90, 20, 0.  Plz refer example of [dynamic scoping](http://www.gatementor.com/viewtopic.php?f=264&t=10106&start=0)